# How do I include shell scripts in a conda recipe?

Tags: anaconda, conda

When building a conda package, meta.yaml has a section `build:entry_points` which lets me include executable Python scripts. Does conda have a way to include other scripts (ex. bash scripts)?

I need conda to include my bash script in the bin/ folder of my environment and make it executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your build.sh script, do something like this:

cp your_bash_script.sh $PREFIX/bin/destination_script_name.sh

Permissions should be preserved.

Edit: to explain a bit more: any files that exist in $PREFIX that were not there before the build step are considered "new" and bundled up with the package.  It's a lot simpler than fighting setup.py, once you get used to it.

Comment: I like it -- very powerful. But not totally obvious. This should be included in the docs somewhere (possibly in a note below the `build:entry_points` section. It opens up conda packages to the world beyond Python.